# How do I use match to indicate PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER for my host and share extension in ios app?

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, fastlane

I simply use following option for gym:

```
def archive(options)
  build_ios_app(
    workspace: PLZ_WORKSPACE,
    scheme: options[:scheme],
    clean: true,
    export_method: options[:adhoc] ? "ad-hoc" : "app-store",
    output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH,
    export_options: {
      signingStyle: "manual", #added to make it working
      provisioningProfiles: { 
        options[:bundle_id] => options[:provisioning],
        options[:share_bundle_id] => options[:share_provisioning]
      },
    },
    #xcargs: { :PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER => options[:provisioning] },
  )
end
```

Commented line must be defined for both targets different way:

for my host app (`options[:bundle_id]`):

```
#xcargs: { :PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER => options[:provisioning] },
```

and for my share extension (`options[:share_bundle_id]`)

```
#xcargs: { :PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER => options[:share_provisioning] },
```

Is there a way to do this here using Fastlane match? I do not want to keep everything in separated repository. I just need to make that one change here.

### Edit

Maybe [update_project_provisioning](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/update_project_provisioning/) is the case to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I used previously the `xcargs` option, but for two provisioning profiles, it works without this, and only using `export_method` and `export_options`:

```rb
def xcode_build
  gym(
    workspace:        "ios/#{xcode_workspace}.xcworkspace",
    scheme:           xcode_workspace,
    output_directory: 'ios',
    output_name:      File.basename(Config.artifacts_path.ios),
    export_method:    match_type.export,
    export_options:   {
      signingStyle:         'manual',
      provisioningProfiles: {
        app_identifier.fetch(:default)   => "match #{match_type.profile} #{app_identifier.fetch(:default)}",
        app_identifier.fetch(:onesignal) => "match #{match_type.profile} #{app_identifier.fetch(:onesignal)}"
      }
    }
  )
end
```

The `match_type` values are one of:

`match_type.export`: `'ad-hoc'` or `'app-store'`
`match_type.profile`: `'AdHoc'` or `'AppStore'`

More information is available at the 'Gym' official documentation.
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/